# The best solution to build a website mobile appliction use phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm building an forum like website and also provide a mobile version, which will detect user agent and return page built on jQuery mobile. However, it will be great to have its mobile application for iphone, android and other platform so user can use their camera and gps from mobile to upload picture and determine their location.Therefore, I turned into phonegap.

I'm new to phonegap and what I'm trying to do is:

1. for reading my forum content, how can I reuse my mobile version

Due to the cross domain communication, I'm thinking JSONP. But it's kind of waste to re-produce the page. (I need to parse JSON, and dynamically create DOM element) Since my mobile version's page has all page elements, can I simply load the page?

or ChildBrowser? to load my mobile version website? Just heard Childbrowser today, can any one share experience?

2 . develop a post form page.
I'm going to use phonegap's camera api. is it possible for this form page also load remotely?

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to look at the documentation provided
 http://docs.phonegap.com/

The google group for phoneGap is great, and very active

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap

You should be able to read your forum content is you create an API that will allow for AJAX calls from the phoneGap Application

I do not believe you are going to have a cross-domain issue from inside the phoneGap Application

Pretty thorough [Camera Demo Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)

And I have posted some PhoneGap related stuff on [my blog](http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com)

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. but your blog seems down. I updated my question. Could you please give me any hint?

Comment: yeah I just noticed, tumblr is down.. but if your webapp is just a rehash of your mobile web pages, there is a good chance that Apple will reject it

Comment: tumblr is back up and so is my blog, hopefully you can find some answers there